# How to avoid double dot when using Excel enums with the interop

Tags: c#, enums, office-interop, excel-interop

When using the Excel interop with C#, it is [advised that you never use "two dots" on one object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/158752/1011724). How do I avoid doing that when trying to use one of the built in enum types such as would happen when I want to change the axis limits of a chart:

```
Excel.Axis ax = chart.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue);
```

note I have declared

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

So my question is how do I write `Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue` with out using two dots?

Comment: You don't have to worry about that. An enum defined under the library's scope is not the same as the `Worksheets` issue from the question you've linked. I doubt an enum has anything to do with COM objects, but rather is just mapped to appropriate values within the language.

Comment: I agree with @SimpleVar. You can test this by using the integer equivalent of the enum value in place of the enum. In the case you show, use 2 instead of `Excel.XlAsixType.xlValue` and it should work just the same.

Comment: @SimpleVar thanks, I was hoping that would be the case